# How to extract the first X characters of a string and use them into another in C

Tags: c, hash, salt, crypt

I have made this function to extract the first 2 characters of a string:

```
string get_salt(string hash)
{
    char pre_salt[2];

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        pre_salt[i] = hash[i];
    }
    string salt = pre_salt;
    printf("%s\n", salt);
    return(salt);
}
```

But when I run it with a string that has "50" (is the example I'm using) as the first 2 characters, I get this output:

```
50r®B
```

And to be honest I have no idea why is it adding the 3 extra characters to the resulting string.

Comment: Is this C or C++?

Comment: Strings in C need to be NUL terminated. Make sure `pre_salt` is one larger than the number of characters and ensure last element is 0.

Comment: Missing zero-terminator, also C doesn't have a "string" type, so a function can't return one. If you're using "string" as a synonym for "char*", then your function is returning a local that will go out of scope.

Comment: Just tried that adding a '\0' to the last element of the sting and worked out! I'm using a library that has the string data type into it so even though I'm using C, I'm able to pass string type variables to functions as inputs or outputs. I have a question, what's the difference of declaring a char* variable instead of a char variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the string's NUL terminator '\0' so it keeps printing until it finds one.
Declare it like:

```
char  pre_salt[3]={0,0,0};
```

And problem solved.

Comment: Probably still returning a pointer to a local that will go out of scope.

Comment: I used a slight variation of this :) I initialized pre_salt to size 3, and after the for loop I added to the last element a '\0'. Thanks!